# "No module named djangomako.middleware" from Intellij developed Django app

Tags: python, django, intellij-idea

When developing a Python application using Intellij, I get:

```
No module named djangomako.middleware
```

when trying to access pages through the development HTTP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ automatically adds Mako as an Middleware application to `settings.py`.

To fix:

1. Edit `<application name>/settings.py`
2. Find `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` definition
3. Remove `'djangomako.middleware.MakoMiddleware'` from list